# test content of a Text element in a stateful component

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-testing-library. My component is quite simple:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {information} from './core/information';

export default class Logo extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: ''
    };
    information()
      .then((details) => {
        this.setState({
          name: details['name']
        });
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <View>

          <Text>{this.state.name}</Text>

        </View>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to make sure  contains the right content. I tried the following but it is failing:

```
import * as info from "./lib/information";

it('displays correct text', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(info, 'information')
    const data = {'name':'name'}
    spy.mockResolvedValue(Promise.resolve(data));

    const {queryByText, debug} = render(<Logo />);
    expect(queryByText(data.name)).not.toBeNull();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

I can confirm the function information() was spied on correctly but still debug(Logo) shows the Text element with empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's correctly spying you can try this. I encourage you to use the `testID` props for the components

```
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <View>

          <Text testID="logo-text">{this.state.name}</Text>

        </View>
      </>
    );
  }
```

```
import * as info from "./lib/information";
import { waitForElement, render } from "react-native-testing-library";

it('displays correct text', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(info, 'information')
    const data = {'name':'name'}
    //this is already resolving the value, no need for the promise
    spy.mockResolvedValue(data);

    const {getByTestId, debug} = render(<Logo />);
    //You better wait for the spy being called first and then checking
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

    //Spy function involves a state update, wait for it to be updated
    await waitForElement(() => getByTestId("logo-text"));
    expect(getByTestId("logo-text").props.children).toEqual(data.name);
  });
```

Also, you should move your information call inside a `componentDidMount`

Comment: just had to do : expect(getByTestId("logo-text").props.children).toEqual(data.name)

Comment: Ah, my bad. I always forget to add that part when testing texts haha. Thanks, I'll fix it